# Problems with Socket io client in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, sockets, socket.io, nuxt.js

I have had some trouble using socket.io client in Nuxt. When i create a socket.io client instance, multiple connections are created. I'm working with vue-socket.io, I had no problems until I needed to add options and create a socket.io client instance. I have tried other libraries and had the same problems.

I have it written in a plugin and import it into my nuxt.config

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

const options = {
  transport: ["polling", "websocket"],
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        Authorization: '', //'Bearer h93t4293t49jt34j9rferek...'
      }
    }
} };

//This code working
// export default function () {
//  Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
//    debug: false,
//    connection: 'http://localhost:3001',
//  }))
// }


//This code not Working
export default function () {
 Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
   debug: false,
   connection: SocketIO('http://localhost:3001', options),
 }))
}
```

This shows the console. The problem is not the back, I tried with public sockets and I also have problems

```
[Nest] 4796   - 25/06/2021 11:30:28 a. m.   [MessageGateway] Client connected: A6TOQpVNSI_b-d5sAAAJ
[Nest] 4796   - 25/06/2021 11:30:29 a. m.   [MessageGateway] Client connected: 7FZyW_K9VtgI3_p1AAAK
[Nest] 4796   - 25/06/2021 11:30:31 a. m.   [MessageGateway] Client connected: TN1hvjkkEN5vC7xEAAAL
[Nest] 4796   - 25/06/2021 11:30:36 a. m.   [MessageGateway] Client connected: X8HUyvr3iJtWvPY7AAAM
[Nest] 4796   - 25/06/2021 11:30:41 a. m.   [MessageGateway] Client connected: MniYR9ketxpmUWBZAAAN
```

nuxt.config

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/apexchart.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false },
    { src: '@/plugins/element-ui.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/vue-cryptoicon.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/v-calendar.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/api.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/dashboard.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/coins.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/wallets.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/accounting.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/deposits.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/investments.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '@/plugins/investments.plugin.client.ts', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
    { src: '~/plugins/socket.client.ts'},
  ],
```

Comment: Where is this code written?

Comment: @kissu I have it written in a plugin and import it into my nuxt.config